# Please merge and synonymize [forums] and [forum]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Both [forums](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forums) and [forum](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forum) exist, have questions, and have a tag wiki.

The former has more questions than the latter. Can they be merged and synonymized, please?